# how do you link static pages in rails to your css files?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

i have my css files where they need to be, now how to i link them to the html, i know i cant use traditional ways like just using a link tag, any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your css files in assets/stylesheets then add

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

into your  html tag (should be in layouts/application.html.erb)

Comment: @nicolas_maloeuvre thank you, i have asked this question many times on this site, but everyone ijust gives me links to places i have already looked for the answer, why does it have to be so hard to get a dang answer on this site

Comment: @dylan, just made a search: it has been answered several times. Before asking a question, it would be good to get to know those basics. Because the answers are on those sites.

Comment: You learn more if you navigate and explore yourself and ask yourself rather than copy&paste

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the [Getting Started Guide of Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#hello-rails-bang).

**Update:** also, there is a separate article of the [Asset Pipeline](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets).

Comment: thanks man i appreciate that